# SQL Server NOT IN and LIKE using together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b032f0a96cd3b54aad32fdea3954f81b) here and my goal is to filter out the emails from the `CUS` table's `email` column where `CMT` table does not have a record for `cmt = 3` and `CUS` table's `email` field `LIKE 'Ack%'`.

Ex : According to the sample data set the expected result should be only `Ack:email3@email.com`, since `order_no = 186350 and 186351` are the ones that does not have a `Comment 3` in the `cmt` field also has `Ack` in the beginning of the `email` field on `CUS` table.

What I have tried but was not successful:

```
SELECT U.email
FROM CUS U inner join CMT M ON U.order_no = M.ord_no
WHERE M.cmt like 'Ack%'
AND U.order_no NOT IN (
    SELECT L.ord_no
    FROM CMT L
    WHERE L.cmt_sql_no = 3
);
```

Appreciate your help!

Sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE CMT (
  id INT,
  ord_type char(1),
  ord_no char(8),
  line_sql_no smallint,
  cmt_sql_no smallint,
  cmt nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (1,'O','186349',0,1,'Comment 1');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (2,'O','186349',0,2,'Comment 2');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (3,'O','186349',0,3,'Comment 3');

INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (4,'O','186350',0,1,'Comment 1');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (5,'O','186350',0,2,'Comment 2');

INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (6,'O','186351',0,1,'Comment 1');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (7,'O','186351',0,2,'Comment 2');

INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (8,'O','186352',0,1,'Comment 1');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (9,'O','186352',0,2,'Comment 2');
INSERT INTO CMT (id,ord_type,ord_no,line_sql_no,cmt_sql_no,cmt) VALUES (10,'O','186352',0,3,'Comment 3');
SELECT * FROM CMT

CREATE TABLE CUS (
  id INT,
  ord_type char(1),
  order_no nchar(10),
  status char(1),
  email nchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO CUS (id,ord_type,order_no,status,email) VALUES (1,'O','186349','4','Ack:email1@email.com');
INSERT INTO CUS (id,ord_type,order_no,status,email) VALUES (2,'O','186350','4','Inv:email2@email.com');
INSERT INTO CUS (id,ord_type,order_no,status,email) VALUES (3,'O','186351','4','Ack:email3@email.com');
INSERT INTO CUS (id,ord_type,order_no,status,email) VALUES (4,'O','186352','1','Inv:email4@email.com');

SELECT * FROM CUS
```

Comment: One thing I'm noticing:  you say `Ack:email3@email.com` should be returned but you're looking for `like 'Ack Email%'`.  Should that be `like 'Ack:Email%'` ?  Also, please verify you are not working with a case sensitive collation

Comment: @DaleK sorry about that, just updated the question with the sample data set.

Comment: @devlincarnate Thank you very much for pointing out that issue, yes I meant to say `like 'Ack:Email%'`, now the question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be ideally resolved using a *not exists* correlation, the following produces your desired results from the sample data set:

```
select c.email
from customer_comment c
where email like 'Ack:%'
and not exists (
  select * from OELINCMT_SQL o
  where o.ord_no = c.order_no 
    and o.cmt_sql_no = 3
);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59a22940ebfb4ec3f5a9bb08cf71d876)